# In a 2004 Subaru Outback H3.0 (LL Bean) is there any way to repair a leaking fuel tank without removing it?

Tags: fuel-tank, fuel-leak

My fuel tank is leaking.  On a 2004 Subaru Outback H3.0 (LL Bean) you need to remove the entire rear axle and exhaust components (and probably a few more things) to remove the fuel tank.

My Check Engine light is on.  The code is 0442.  The exhaust stinks like one of those old 2-stroke engines or worse.  And the mechanic lifted my car and showed me a wet spot around and under the fuel tank.  So I need to fix this in order to keep this car.  He said the pump is somehow good, but the fuel tank has a leak.

I thought I'd heard of some kinds of rubber inserts or some "arthroscopic" repairs by going into the gasoline nozzle and patching it.  Does anyone know anything about repairing the fuel tank without removing it from the car (from the inside of the tank or something like that).

Comment: It is worth finding out where the leak is ; It could be a hose connection at the fill tube, output tube or the return tube.

Comment: `a wet spot around and under the fuel tank` May not be the tank at all. And my '00 Outback has the same smell. It is a connection on the engine that makes the smell. I looked it up once and it is a known issue with Subaru's when they get old. Take it to a SuBee place, I bet they will know exactly where the smell comes from. $0.02

Comment: Hi Scottie, It would be great if this is something that can be fixed without removing the entire tank. I did some more research and found some info about the possible leaks in the filler neck, some hoses and the charcoal vents. If you jog your memory and remember exactly what it was and how they fixed it, I'd really really appreciate that.